# MySQL SELECT REPLACE part of string

Tags: mysql, select, replace, substring

I have a column with data like this:

```
http://www.example.com/category/link.html
http://www.example2.com/category2/link.html
http://www.example3.com/directory/category/link.php
http://www.example4.com/category4/link.php
http://www.example5.com/directory/link.html
```

I want to select the distinct `domain.com` part of these links, and then insert this into another column

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(domain,'http://www.','') AS domain FROM table;
```

This selects everything without the `http://www.` How do I remove the rest of the link so im left with `domain.com` and then insert this into another column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(domain,'http://www.',''), '/', 1) AS domain
FROM mytable
```

Applying [**`SUBSTRING_INDEX`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) after `'http://www.'` has been eliminated from the domain string, returns the part of the string before the first occurrence of `'/'`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/288d7b/2)

Comment: how can I insert the results into another column?

Comment: @user3312792 Just do an `UPDATE`. It actually depends on which rows you want to update.

Comment: UPDATE mytable SET field = SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(domain,'http://www.',''), '/', 1) AS domain
FROM mytable ?

Comment: @user3312792 No, you can't update this way. You can do `UPDATE mytable SET filed =  SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(domain,'',''), '/', 1)` to update on a row by row basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `substring_index()`.  For instance, this might work on your data:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(col, '/', 3), '.', -2) as domain
```